# jquery .attr() after .append()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm generating a select option programatically however the `.attr()` function after an `.append()` doesn't add the attribute to the just appended element but to the father.

Shouldn't `.append()` return the just appended element?

Here a JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/cq24uv1x/1/

```
$("body").html($("<select>").append("<option>").attr('value',"bla bla bla").append("</option>").append("</select>"));
```

instead of getting a

```
<select><option value="bla bla bla"></option></select>
```

I get a

```
<select value="bla bla bla"><option></option></select>
```

Comment: Because `.append()` returns the original collection, not the element that has been appended (which doesn't even *have* to be an element).

Comment: `.append() return the appended element?` no, it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- https://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/cq24uv1x/2/

**JS:-**

```
$("body").append($("<select>").append($("<option>").attr('value',"bla bla bla")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate some attributes with a newly created item, you can specify an object after the actual element to define their values:

```
var option = $("<option>", {
  'value': 'bla bla bla'
})
$("body").html($("<select>").append(option)...
```

Or to better suite your current syntax:

```
$("body").html($("<select>").append($("<option>", { 'value': 'bla bla bla' })).append($("<option>", .....
```

To better understand why your code is not working as expected, take a look at the actual command you are executing:

```
$("<select>").append("<option>")
```

You are running the `append` function on the `<select>` element and not on the `<option>` element, hence the return value of the `append` function is the object you are appending to: the select element. This is why the next `attr` function adds attributes to the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$("body").html($("<select>").append($(document.createElement('option')).attr('value',"bla bla bla")));
```

In your case, you are calling the `attr` method in the `<select>` attribute. Remember that jQuery has chaining methods, `append` returns `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Is Not Working Because .attr is Set attribute Of
Try This

```
$("body").html($("<select>").append("<option>test Option").append("</option>").append("</select>"));
$('option').attr('value',"bla bla bla");
```